# Are closed ecological systems considered terraforming?

Tags: terraforming

With the recent interest in traveling to Mars, it would seem apparent that terraforming would be an integral part of achieving this goal.

Is it a requirement to encompass the whole planet, or is a [CES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_ecological_system) considered terraforming as well? What are the current active or proposed projects to accomplish terraforming?

Comment: I've never heard "terraforming" used to refer to a closed environment (except to the extent that you can consider an entire planet a closed environment). I think using "terraforming" for that would be unnecessarily confusing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming

Comment: Even if it's transforming the original environment? A CES on the moon is as much about changing the environment, as it is maintaining homeostasis within the new environment. It seems strange to draw a distinction in size compared to what the Wikipedia page refers to as "paraterraforming".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction between a closed ecosystem and paraterraforming is whether the purpose is to create a livable habitat or to alter the planet's environment. I would argue that domed cities, etc are not terraforming, but if you somehow start doming massive regions, then it is.

I guess to me the difference is whether you're creating a livable environment to fill your short-term needs, or whether you're transforming regions that will remain unused for the foreseeable future.